# Jenkins job not seeing console output

Tags: shell, jenkins, build

First, I'm not the admin, so there might be something config-wise that's not correct, leading to this issue.  I can configure the one job I have access to configure and that is all.

I am performing a Windows build, using a combination of shell scripts (using git-bash.exe) and Windows batch file.  The sole jenkins build script is a shell script containing only:

```
#!c:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
$WORKSPACE/builds/step1.sh |& tee $WORKSPACE/build_output.log
```

(My git-bash.exe version is '4.3.42(5)-release' and the `|&` shorthand appears to be working as well as `2>&1 |` did.)

That script (step1.sh) does some prep work and then kicks off the build process by calling batch files and shell scripts in sequence.

The build works and I am rewarded with a nice MSI file.  The build_output.log file contains a full log of the entire build process as was also displayed in the console on the slave.

The problem is, jenkins fails to capture that console output (ie, the contents of build_output.log).  All I see for console output is:

```
Started by user Jon
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Win2k12r2_x64-build (Build VM (xx.xx.xx.xx) Windows Client) in workspace /f/git/project
[project] $ c:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\hudson386179994146389782.sh
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

What do I need to do to capture the build log in jenkins?  I specifically don't want to put my step1.sh script into jenkins since I want to be able to exactly reproduce what the build team (who manage the jenkins server) see when a build fails.  We want the build scripts under source control, available to all and runnable by all (in their own sandbox).  I did try simply cat-ing the build log from the jenkins two-line shell script to see if that captured it... it did not.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a similar command in Jenkins to tee a log:

```
./foo.sh 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

(The version of `git-bash.exe` on the Jenkins server I was using did not support `|&`, so I had to use the long form to redirect stderr.)

In your case, if neither the console log or `build_output.log` contain any text, I'm guessing it's one of the following:

1. `step1.sh` is not actually outputting anything

   **Troubleshoot:** Run that script in Jenkins without any redirection or `tee`, and verify it prints something to the console. Don't rely only on a local run in case something in your Jenkins environment (such as a Jenkins plugin) is causing the problem.
2. `|&` is silently failing

   **Troubleshoot:** Configure your job to run `echo foo>&2 |& cat`, and verify you see "foo" in your console. If that fails, try the long form: `echo foo>&2 2>&1 | cat`.
3. `tee` is silently failing

   **Troubleshoot:** Configure your job to run `echo foo>&2 |& tee out.txt`, and verify you see "foo" in both your console and `out.txt`. If that fails, try the long form: `echo foo>&2 2>&1 | tee out.txt`.

Comment: Oddly, the `echo foo>&2...` doesn't work (tee does not get the output) but removing the '>&2' allows it (the tests you asked me to try) to proceed.  I see 'foo' in the console window on the slave  and in the log, but, not in the Console Output on the jenkins server.  Neither does running a simple script 'bob.sh' on the slave, containing only `#!/bin/sh.exe^Mecho foo` - I see the output on the slave's console window that pops up briefly and in the output log file, but not on the jenkins server.  My original build script outputs on the slave and to the log file, but nothing captured in jenkins.

Comment: You say you see the "console window pop up briefly". Are you spawning new console windows in your `sh` script? If so, that could be your problem. Can you post an example of your script?

Comment: No, step1.sh will either "call" a batch file, or execute a shell script, all within the context of the console window in which step1.sh is running.